# How to convert a String array into int array in Java without using a loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, type-conversion

I have a String array of numbers that I read in from a data file using a Scanner:

```
6 10 13 14 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185
```

I take a line from the file and convert it into a String array. Is there a simple way to convert the String array into an  int array without a for loop?

```
String indices = input.nextLine();
String[] clean = indices.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: Why do you need to avoid a loop, is this an assignment of some sort? Are utility functions allowed or are you after a recursive solution?

Comment: I don't need to avoid it, I just thought there might be some sort of method to this in less lines.

Comment: Similar, but I'm specifically looking for ways without a loop.

Comment: That question has answers that avoid loops (or at least: the loops are hidden from you, because believe me: loops will be used internally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a `forloop` may involve `Streams` and mapping :

```
String indices = input.nextLine();
int[] array = Arrays.stream(indices.split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
// [6, 10, 13, 14, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185]
```

Comment: Technically, that involves a loop under-the-hood, right?

Comment: Nevermind, looks like this is what OP was asking for.